# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. When trying to send HTML through mail.send with Powershell

Tags: html, powershell, graph

I am trying to send custom built html through a variable in PowerShell when trying to use mail.send in the Graph API. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request is what returns when trying to do so. Please refer to the following code as an example:

```
$MailSender = user@domain.com

$reportBody = "<!DOCTYPE html>

<HTML>

<head>

<title>Distribution Groups Email Notification</title>



<style>

body {

font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;



background-color: white;

color: #000000;

}



table {

border: 0px;

border-collapse: separate;

padding: 3px;

}



tr, td, th { padding: 3px; }



th {

color: #FFFFFF;

font-weight: bold;

text-align: center;

}



h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 { color: #002C54; }

</style></head><BODY>

<h2 align="center">Distribution Groups Report</h2>

<h4 align="center">9/13/2021 2:40:01 PM</h4>

</font> <br><table>

<tr bgcolor="#325777"><th>Created On</th><th>Created By</th><th>DG Display Name</th><th>DG Email Address</th><th># Members</th><tr><td>09/13/2021 14:05:26</td><td>isaiah.hanson@domain.com</td><td>Isaiahstest2</td><td>Isaiahstest2@domain.com</td><td>0</td></table></BODY></HTML>"

    #Send Mail    
    $URLsend = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$MailSender/sendMail"
    $BodyJsonsend = @"
                    {
                        "message": {
                          "subject": "Distribution Group Report",
                          "body": @{
                            "contentType": "HTML",
                            "content": $reportBody
                            
                            
                          },
                          "toRecipients": [
                            {
                              "emailAddress": {
                                "address": "user@domain.com"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "saveToSentItems": "false"
                      }
"@
```

I have tested sending a generic email through the Graph API and it works great. I also tried running running the HTML plainly in a browser and it shows up great.

Part of me wonders if its too much for graph to hand, or if there are limitation to HTML in the Graph API.

Any Suggestions?

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If "contentType" refers to a mime type, you'd want that to be "text/html", rather than "HTML".</strike>

Just checked the docs, "HTML" looks right: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

But it looks like there are a few extra "@"'s in the code you posted. Is that the correct form? That doesn't look like valid JSON to me.

Comment: I tried changing "HTML" to "text/html" and still got bad request 400. :(

Comment: Still got 400 when removing the @ after "body". Are there suppose to be any @'s at all?

Comment: Any other recommendations?

Comment: I'd remove the @ after the `=`, the one after `"body":` and the one at the very end, then try it again.